# How to transform multiple dates into a JSON object into custom formatted dates using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have a JSON object, that comes from an AJAX request, represented by an interface `SuccesResponse`

```
interface SuccessResponse {
    dates: Dates;
}
```

Where:

```
interface Dates {
    items: DatesItemResponse[];
}

interface DatesItemResponse {
    date: string;
}
```

A `DatesItemResponse` looks like this:

```
{
    "date": "2018-06-25T00:00:00"
}
```

I need to format all those dates using `moment.js` as `MM-DD`, so in the example above it should be `06-25`, but I don't know how to make `moment.js` parse all the dates instead of a single one.

Comment: `moment(obj.date).format('MM-DD')`

Comment: Why use moment? `DatesItemResponse.date.substr(5,5)` does it for me (and it's less code). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

According to the interfaces you mention, your response looks something like this:

```
const response = {
    dates: {
        items: [{
            date: '2018-06-25T00:00:00'
        }, {
            date: '2018-06-26T00:00:00'
        }, {
            date: '2018-06-27T00:00:00'
        }]
    }
};
```

Therefore, you need to iterate over `items` and parse all the `date` properties in there by [creating a moment object with each date string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and then calling [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) on those moment objects with the desired format, `MM-DD` in this case.

If you want to get all the dates in a single array, you could use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and do something like this:

```js
const response = {
    dates: {
        items: [{
            date: '2018-06-25T00:00:00'
        }, {
            date: '2018-06-26T00:00:00'
        }, {
            date: '2018-06-27T00:00:00'
        }]
    }
};

console.log(response.dates.items.map(item => moment(item.date).format('MM-DD')));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, if you want to get the exact same object you had initially, but with the original date strings replaced with the formatted ones, then [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) might be a better option (though technically, `map` would also work):

```js
const response = {
    dates: {
        items: [{
            date: '2018-06-25T00:00:00'
        }, {
            date: '2018-06-26T00:00:00'
        }, {
            date: '2018-06-27T00:00:00'
        }]
    }
};

response.dates.items.forEach(item => {
  item.date = moment(item.date).format('MM-DD');
});

console.log(response);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting the date object as an ajax response from an API and I am therefore not able to use the JSON.parse(). Do you have a workaround?

Comment: @OliverJuhl Could you please update your question with the code of that AJAX call?

Comment: If the response has already been parsed, you might just need to do `moment(response.date).format('MM-DD')` or `moment(response.data.date).format('MM-DD')`, without using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the ajax request success response.

Comment: For some reason I cant fetch the props of the objects, that lies within JSON object.

Comment: @OliverJuhl Take a look at the updated answer. Basically, if you have multiple dates nested into that response object, you need to iterate over all of them and create multiple moment objects (one for each date) to parse them all.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Danziger